# Jest has detected open handle keeping Jest from exiting in Gitlab Ci

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, gitlab-ci, nestjs

I get this error in my shared gitlab runner.

[image]

But if I run the tests locally I don't get any error.

[image]

How can I debug this? the error message says nothing to me.
Which information do you need to help me? Sorry, I can't upload the whole project.

What is wrong with jest?

Comment: You might want to consider asking this question here too: https://superuser.com/

Comment: Can you post your test?

Comment: all test or what should i post?

Comment: @DanielDäschle Based on the error message it would be nice to see `activities.service.spec.ts`

Comment: ok, i didn't found anything in there. i got it working by creating a new branch and implement everything new step by step. now it is working. i think i broke something anywhere and i didn't found it. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in unit tests when you don't close an async operation. This could for example be a CronJob:

```
const job = new CronJob('00 00 8,14,18 * * *', () => this.sendNotificationsPerUser());
job.start();
```

In this case, you have to make sure that `job.stop()` is called before the test ends. This can easily be avoided by providing those async libraries as services and then mocking them in your test.

---

In e2e tests, you have to make sure that you close the application after the test has run:

```
afterAll(async () => {
  if (app) {
    await app.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: That what i run are unit tests and not e2e tests. So i should not have to close any app.